# how to restrict number of service replicas in docker to 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run an application in docker swarm mode, I have a stateful service(container) like db which should have only single instance in entire application, and my application has other containers like web-app which can scale to any number.

how can I restrict the scaling of service to 1:

we can specify by default in docker-compose version :3 as

```
deploy:  
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
```

but this will at app deploy time only once the app is deployed using 
docker stack deploy

anyone can scale(unknowingly) the db service to more than 1, which I want to avoid.

is there any way in compose file to restrict the number replicas of a service  to 1, in the entire lifetime of the application